# How to setup .htaccess In Codeigniter on Ubuntu 14.04 Lamp Stack Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have no idea how to proceed, I checked many tutorial did step by step but no success, I started think it is something on my apache not running well.

I am not the server person and always I get stuck in that stuff, my site its running well on my local but after transfer it to a server, the problems start.

If you can help me, I will appreciate it.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
mysite.com.conf
```

```
   # domain: mysite.com
    # public: /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    #error 403
        <Directory "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/blog">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
              RewriteEngine On
              RewriteBase /blog/
              RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
            </IfModule>
        </Directory>

         <Directory "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
        </Directory>

      # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
      DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html
      # Log file locations
      LogLevel warn
      ErrorLog  /var/www/mysite.com/log/error.log
      CustomLog /var/www/mysite.com/log/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
#for the error 403

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

/etc/apache2
apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess file in my root

```
 RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your example.com.conf as simple as this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName      example.com
ServerAlias     www.example.com
DocumentRoot    /var/www/example.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

After saving and closing this file, make sure you enable your VirtualHost by typing: sudo a2ensite example.com.conf

Now restart apache, sudo service apache2 restart

This is how your .htaccess in /var/www/example.com/public_html should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

In your application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

Try these settings and let me know if it works fine for you.

Comment: hello thanks for the help, but still not working, look: my app is here: /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/myapp , should i put the .htaccess inside root of myapp or just in public_html: i tried both and still not working :(

Comment: If all your CodeIgniter files and directories are under myapp directory, then your .htaccess file should be at /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/myapp/.htaccess and your VirtualHost file DocumentRoot should point to: /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/myapp

Comment: @user964836 give this a try. Download fresh copy of CI and extract it to /var/www/example.com so that your application directory should be here: /var/www/example.com/application . Now follow all the steps I mentioned above and see if it works. Just to confirm, is your rewrite module activated? If not, then run this command: sudo a2enmod rewrite and restart your apache.

Comment: i will try do that, yeah my rewrite mode is activated , many thanks i will do